# Python code runs but is does not execute all steps

Tags: python-2.7, conditional-statements

I picked up Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python recently. Trying to do one of the exercises. Here are the instructions:

Write a program that examines three variables - x,y, and z - and prints the largest odd number among them. If none are odd, it should print a message to that effect.

Here is my code:

```
print 'Please enter three numbers:'

x = input('First number: ')

y = input('Second number: ')

z = input('Third number: ')

if x%2 == 1:
    if x > y and y > z:
        print x

elif y%2 == 1:
    if y > x and x > z:
        print y

elif z%2 == 1:
    if y > x and z > y:
        print z

else:
    print 'None of your numbers are odd'
```

This is what the python shell outputs when I run the code:

```
Please enter three numbers:

First number: 3

Second number: 8

Third number: 17
```

The book uses Python 2.7.11 so that's the version I am using. I am not sure why the code only runs the three inputs but not the conditional statements.

Comment: Your code is run ok.x%2 ==1 but x is not smaller you,  so no other print statements are run.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to pass one condition but not the condition that would print out another. For example, if `x%2==1` is true, that block of code in the `if` statement will be entered, but if the second condition is not met, it will not look through the rest of the conditions. With the numbers you entered, you'll see that you enter the first `if` statement, and so the rest of the statements will be ignored regardless of whether or not the nested `if` statement has its conditions met. Therefore, you might print something out between nested statements, like so:

```
if x%2 == 1:
    print 'x is an odd number.'
    if x > y and y > z:
        print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simply answering your question I provided a few small changes with explanations to help you get started.

The first change is with regard to the use of if and elif statements. In your code if x is odd the if statement is executed and none of the elif statements will be executed. None of the other numbers will be checked.

if a number is even I set it to zero so it won't be larger than the largest positive odd number.

If a number is odd you want to make sure it is larger than the other two so rather than testing x > y and y > z you want to check if x > y and x > z.

Finally, the last if statement checks to see if they were all even.

```
print 'Please enter three numbers:'
x = input('First number: ')
y = input('Second number: ')
z = input('Third number: ')

# if values are even set them to zero so they won't be the largest numbers
if x%2 == 0:
    x = 0
if y%2 == 0:
    y = 0
if z%2 == 0:
    z = 0

if x%2 == 1:
    if x > y and x > z:
    print x

if y%2 == 1:
    if y > x and y > z:
        print y

if z%2 == 1:
    if z > x and z > y:
        print z

if x == 0 and y == 0 and z == 0:
    print 'None of your numbers are odd'
```